# USB Type-C EMCA cable - where does the mux happen?

Tags: usb, usb-device, usb-host

If I wanted to re-route SBU1 and SBU2 to a separate controller because I only intend to use the USB 2.0 capabilities of the wire - Do I have to worry about the EMCA chip interfering?

Does the USB MUX happen in a EMCA cable - or does it happen host/device side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few mix-ups here.

1. Electronic Marker is connected to CC1/CC2 wires, so they can't interfere with auxiliary wires;
2. There is no SBU wires in a Type-C USB 2.0 cable. You will need to use a full-blown USB 3.1 Type-C cable assembly for this.
3. No USB cable does any MUX. Ever.
4. I wouldn't worry about eMarked cables at all. They are reaaly difficult to come by.

Comment: Thank you!

(1) This is what I kept seeing in the diagrams - I just wanted to be absolutely sure.

(2) I should have clarified. I am only interested in using the 2.0 capabilities of a Type-C wire at the moment, I do not intend to use a USB 2.0 cable as it is only required to use 4 wires.

(3) That is good news. I kept finding chips in type-c cables and I couldn't tell if they were only ID chips OR if they did more. Makes sense that the MUX is on the other side of the port.